# Instantiation of Kivy Children Widgets between Python and Kivy Language

Tags: python, kivy

I am having issues getting Kivy to instantiate children Widgets. The issue here I believe is with how I am setting up the root widget. According to many examples I have seen including kivy's own [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#instantiate-children) I should be able to instantiate children widgets to a root widget in the .kv file without using <> as such:

**initApp.kv root_rule:**

```
Root_Widget:
    Test_Screen:

<Test_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
       *there is stuff here, leaving blank to keep this question shorter*
```

**Python File: (Note that the add_widget() is commented out)**

```
class Test_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Root_Widget(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.add_widget(Test_Screen())
    pass

class InitApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root_Widget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    InitApp().run()
```

However, this only leads to a blank app. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Uncomment the **self.add_widget(Test_Screen())** line OR
2. Add <> to around the Root_Widget in the .kv file so it would then be a class rule:

**initApp.kv class_rule:**

```
<Root_Widget>:
    Test_Screen:

<Test_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        *there is stuff here, leaving blank to keep this question shorter*
```

**Question**

My question is, what is the difference here? Nesting Test_Screen underneath Root_Widget in the .kv file should be the exact same as calling the add_widget() method correct? Is this true and if so how/why is it different when setting Root_Widget as a class rule VS. a root rule?

Are there unforeseen consequences to saying that Root_Widget is a class rule rather than a root rule? It seems to work just fine using this approach but I don't know if it will cause other trouble as the app becomes more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Blank Window/App

The blank window/app could be due to one of the following:

- kv file name mismatch e.g. app class name, `class InitApp(App):` then kv filename should be `init.kv`. If you are not using *Builder* to load kv then the kv file name should be *init.kv* and not *InitApp.kv*
- No root widget in the *return* statement
- No [root rule](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#rule-context) in the kv file

[kv filename - By name convention](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv)

> **By name convention**
>
> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in
>   lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:
>
> ```
> MyApp -> my.kv
> ```

### Solution - Blank Window/App

Instantiate and add a Label widget under Test_Screen as follow:

```
<Test_Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "kv file - Root Rule vs Class Rule"
```

## Question 1

> what is the difference here? Nesting Test_Screen underneath
>   Root_Widget in the kv file should be the exact same as calling the
>   add_widget() method correct?

## Answer 1

Yes it is the same.

### Kivy App - without kv file

- Use `add_widget(Test_Screen())` function to instantiate add children widgets under the parent.

### Kivy App - with kv file

- Instantiate and add children widgets under the parent using `Test_Screen:`
- Can use both e.g. using `add_widget(Button())` to dynamically instantiate and add children widgets to a ScrollView.

## Question 2

> Is this true and if so how/why is it different when setting
>   Root_Widget as a class rule VS. a root rule?

## Answer 2

When the kv file is parsed, the root rule will be set as the root attribute of the App instance. Whereas a class rule, defines how any instance of that class will be graphically represented.

## Question 3

Are there unforeseen consequences to saying that Root_Widget is a class rule rather than a root rule?

## Answer 3

I don't believe there is any unforeseen consequences. The only thing to note when using ***root rule*** or ***class rule*** in kv file are as follow.

### kv file - Using root rule

If in your kv file, you have a root rule defined i.e. `Root_Widget:` then in your Python code, you can do one of the following:

### Option 1

The kv file is *init.kv*

```
class InitApp(App):
    pass
```

### Option 2

The kv file is not *init.kv* but *InitApp.kv*

```
class InitApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("InitApp.kv")
```

### kv file - Using class rule

If in your kv file, you have a class rule defined i.e. `<Root_Widget>:` then in your Python code, you can do one of the following:

### Option 1

The kv file is *init.kv*

```
class InitApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Root_Widget()
```

### Option 2

The kv file is not *init.kv* but *InitApp.kv*

```
class InitApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("InitApp.kv")
        return Root_Widget()
```

Comment: Thanks ikolim! Your answer was very helpful. I edited the question because I did have a label and buttons and stuff in the defined for Test_Screen in the .kv files I just didn't include it to keep the question more concise. Anyway, option 1 of answer 3 solved the blank screen issue I was seeing when trying to use the root rule in the .kv file. So, now I can use all the different instantiation techniques